# Replace Tork 1101 timer with smart switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, timer, smart-switch

I have a Tork 1101 mechanical timer that controls exterior house lights. I want to replace this with a smart timer/switch of some kind so I can set a sunrise/sunset scheme and don't need to remember to change it. I have two questions:

1. How is this wired?
2. Can I replace this with any smart wall switch?

Here is a photo, thanks!

[image: Tork 1101 timer box]

Comment: How much load is this switch controlling?

Comment: It's controlling: 1 exterior motion-sensing light fixture, another exterior fixture that is always on with two high output LED bulbs, and a porch light fixture with two CFL or LED bulbs that is always on.

Comment: This timer is mounted indoors, correct?

Comment: Yes, mounted next to the service panel in the basement.

Comment: Do you have the actual wattage of those high output LED bulbs, and what does the motion sensor have in it for bulbs for that matter? Also, what gauge are those wires feeding the timer?

Comment: I was off - it's actually:
(1) Always on fixture - 2 bulbs @ 20W, (1) Porch light - 2 bulbs @ 16W, (2) Motion-sensor fixtures - 4 bulbs @ 20W.

I rounded the wattages up. No additional fixtures will be added to the outside of the house.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I don't know the gauge of the wires. I did not wire this and I'm not sure why it's using stranded wire.

Comment: Those wires come out of a conduit (nipple), right?

Comment: Yes, it's coming from the panel right next to it, through an offset conduit nipple. Have not opened that panel up.

Comment: Vincent, were you able to replace for a smart switch? Which one did you buy?

Comment: @Ashley Yes, I replaced it with a Kasa Smart Switch Model HS200. It has been working great for a few years now. I use the built in sunrise/sunset routines in the Kasa app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Go for it

You should be able to get a deep single gang "handy" box and fit it to the nipple in place of the existing timer enclosure, then fit whatever smart switch into that box that you wish, given that you're only trying to switch ~150W of load.  Note that the red wire is your always-hot and the blue your switched-hot, according to how the current timer is connected, with white being the neutral of course.

Comment: I agree and would suggest intermatic astrometric timer. A real pain in the butt to program but they work great the have a special battery that lasts 2 years when it quits working change the battery and put it back in auto, it adjusts the on and off times through out the year if I need more than 20 amps I put a contactor in and drive that. I have 8 or 9 in my plant and keep adding more because they work so well (once programmed).+

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming! I'm looking at the [Kasa Smart Switch](https://www.amazon.com/Kasa-Smart-Light-Switch-TP-Link/dp/B01EZV35QU/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=smart+switch+no+hub+required&qid=1569719430&sr=8-4) since it doesn't require a hub. I don't really want something I need to program, just set a sunrise/sunset routine via an app and be done with it.